# Symfony2, Knp Paginator: use page with prefix in url

Tags: symfony, paginator

I would like to have prefix for page in url, like this:

```
http://host/list/page_5

/**
 * @Route("/list/{page}", name="list", requirements={"page" = "page_\d+"})
```

...

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page') /*page number*/,
            5  /*limit per page*/
        );
```

In case of using just numbers - it works fine. But what is best way to use pagination and these page prefixes in urls?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do this. I personally would use http://host/list/page/5

Answer (score 1):

Change route schema into

```
@Route("/list/page_{page}", name="list", requirements={"page" = "\d+"})
```

Comment: In this case "page" param is required always. Currently solved the issue by parsing param "page" and cut part of string:
substr($page, 5)